# Cassandra read performance collapses on multiple sequential reads

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data, datastax-java-driver, spring-data-cassandra

I have some trouble getting data out of Cassandra.

**Task**
I have an initial load of data which contains 8.1 million of datasets which I save in chunks of 7700 datasets each row. The idea was to keep every partition around 100k column families.
After reading of about 300 chunks or 2 million datasets, the application gets slower and than collapses.

The database needs to provide even more data later, so I hope somebody can tell me, what's going wrong.

**Note**
For development cassandra is installed on a virtual machine, ubuntu linux with 3CPUs and 13GB RAM and OpenJDK8.

**Application Setup**

- Cassandra 2.2.7
- spring-data-cassandra:1.4.5.RELEASE

  - spring-cql:1.4.3.RELEASE
  - spring-data-commons:1.12.3.RELEASE
  - cassandra-driver.dse:2.1.9

**Database Setup**

```
CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS import_test WITH REPLICATION = 
{ 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1 };

CREATE TABLE  transactional_data (
 job varchar,
 client varchar, 
 run int,
 chunk int,
 mdh_id uuid,
 gtin varchar, 
 sender varchar, 
 receiver varchar,
 quantity int,
 ta_id varchar, 
 type varchar,  
 ts timestamp,
 add_info map<text, text>, 
 PRIMARY KEY ((job, client, run, chunk), mdh_id));
```

**Database Start Parameter**
Xms, Xmx and Xmn are manually set, the start script calculated even lower values.

```
java -ea -javaagent:./../lib/jamm-0.3.0.jar -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+UseThreadPriorities -XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42 -Xms4G -Xmx4G -Xmn800M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xss256k -XX:StringTableSize=1000003 -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:SurvivorRatio=8 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=1 -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+UseTLAB -XX:+PerfDisableSharedMem -XX:CompileCommandFile=./../conf/hotspot_compiler -XX:CMSWaitDuration=10000 -XX:+CMSParallelInitialMarkEnabled -XX:+CMSEdenChunksRecordAlways -XX:CMSWaitDuration=10000 -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -XX:+PrintPromotionFailure -Xloggc:./../logs/gc.log -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=10 -XX:GCLogFileSize=10M -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dcassandra.jmx.local.port=7199 -XX:+DisableExplicitGC
```

**Application Code**

```
int chunks = 1053; // chunk size is known
List<List<TransactionalData>> resultLists = new ArrayList<>(chunks);

for (int chunk = 1; chunk <= chunks; chunk++) {
 Select select = QueryBuilder.select().from(TABLE_TRANSACTIONAL_DATA);
 select.where(QueryBuilder.eq(CASSANDRA_COLUMN_JOB, jobId))
  .and(QueryBuilder.eq(CASSANDRA_COLUMN_CLIENT, clientId))
  .and(QueryBuilder.eq(CASSANDRA_COLUMN_RUN, run))
  .and(QueryBuilder.eq(CASSANDRA_COLUMN_CHUNK, chunk));

 StopWatch s = new StopWatch();
 s.start();
 List<TransactionalData> result = cassandraOperations.select(select, TransactionalData.class);
 s.stop();
 log.info("query [" + jobId + ", " + clientId + ", " + run + ", " + chunk + "] returned " + result.size() + " results in " + s.getTotalTimeMillis() + " ms");
 resultLists.add(result);
}
```

**Application log**

```
20:09:26.380  INFO ExportServiceImpl: query [initial, RM, 1, 1] returned 7700 results in 293 ms
[multiple reads between 300 - 400ms]
20:09:40.922  INFO ExportServiceImpl: query [initial, RM, 1, 36] returned 7700 results in 1160 ms
[multiple reads between 300 - 400ms]
20:09:51.785  INFO ExportServiceImpl: query [initial, RM, 1, 64] returned 7700 results in 1701 ms
[multiple reads between 300 - 400ms]
20:10:05.583  INFO ExportServiceImpl: query [initial, RM, 1, 97] returned 7700 results in 2476 ms
[multiple reads between 300 - 600ms]
20:11:00.956  INFO ExportServiceImpl: query [initial, RM, 1, 230] returned 7700 results in 3615 ms
[multiple reads between 300 - 3000ms and suddenly behaviour collapses]
20:11:17.707  INFO ExportServiceImpl: query [initial, RM, 1, 276] returned 7700 results in 370 ms
20:11:23.398  INFO ExportServiceImpl: query [initial, RM, 1, 277] returned 7700 results in 5691 ms
20:11:23.717  INFO ExportServiceImpl: query [initial, RM, 1, 278] returned 7700 results in 319 ms
20:11:24.033  INFO ExportServiceImpl: query [initial, RM, 1, 279] returned 7700 results in 316 ms
20:11:27.289  INFO ExportServiceImpl: query [initial, RM, 1, 280] returned 7700 results in 3256 ms
20:11:27.607  INFO ExportServiceImpl: query [initial, RM, 1, 281] returned 7700 results in 318 ms
20:11:30.380  INFO ExportServiceImpl: query [initial, RM, 1, 282] returned 7700 results in 2773 ms
20:11:30.669  INFO ExportServiceImpl: query [initial, RM, 1, 283] returned 7700 results in 288 ms
[multiple reads time increases up to 10000ms each read]
20:13:55.341  INFO ExportServiceImpl: query [initial, RM, 1, 323] returned 7700 results in 13813 ms
20:14:09.200  INFO ExportServiceImpl: query [initial, RM, 1, 324] returned 7700 results in 13859 ms
20:14:32.799  INFO ExportServiceImpl: query [initial, RM, 1, 325] returned 7700 results in 23599 ms
20:15:05.796  INFO ExportServiceImpl: query [initial, RM, 1, 326] returned 7700 results in 32997 ms

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Proxy.java:710)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils.synthesizeAnnotation(AnnotationUtils.java:1503)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.findMergedAnnotation(AnnotatedElementUtils.java:731)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.BasicCassandraPersistentProperty.isCompositePrimaryKey(BasicCassandraPersistentProperty.java:109)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.BasicCassandraPersistentProperty.getCompositePrimaryKeyType(BasicCassandraPersistentProperty.java:113)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.BasicCassandraPersistentProperty.getCompositePrimaryKeyTypeInformation(BasicCassandraPersistentProperty.java:118)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.BasicCassandraPersistentProperty.getCompositePrimaryKeyEntity(BasicCassandraPersistentProperty.java:394)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.readPropertyFromRow(MappingCassandraConverter.java:164)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.MappingCassandraConverter$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingCassandraConverter.java:148)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.MappingCassandraConverter$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingCassandraConverter.java:143)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:322)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.readPropertiesFromRow(MappingCassandraConverter.java:143)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.readEntityFromRow(MappingCassandraConverter.java:135)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.readRow(MappingCassandraConverter.java:115)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.read(MappingCassandraConverter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraConverterRowCallback.doWith(CassandraConverterRowCallback.java:47)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.select(CassandraTemplate.java:587)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.select(CassandraTemplate.java:354)
    at AbstractExportService.exportData(AbstractExportService.java:79)
    at ExportServiceImpl.exportData(ExportServiceImpl.java:33)
    at ExportServiceImplTest.exportData(ExportServiceImplTest.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
```

**Cassandra System log**

```
19:55:36,960 GCInspector.java:284 - ParNew GC in 715ms.  CMS Old Gen: 2008935960 -> 2008954320; Par Eden Space: 671088640 -> 0; Par Survivor Space: 13605416 -> 16345128
19:55:36,967 StatusLogger.java:52 - Pool Name                    Active   Pending      Completed   Blocked  All Time Blocked
19:55:37,069 StatusLogger.java:56 - MutationStage                     0         0        8321004         0                 0
19:55:37,070 StatusLogger.java:56 - ReadStage                         0         0         256399         0                 0
19:55:37,071 StatusLogger.java:56 - RequestResponseStage              0         0             17         0                 0
19:55:37,080 StatusLogger.java:56 - ReadRepairStage                   0         0              0         0                 0
19:55:37,081 StatusLogger.java:56 - CounterMutationStage              0         0              0         0                 0
19:55:37,083 StatusLogger.java:56 - HintedHandoff                     0         0              0         0                 0
19:55:37,084 StatusLogger.java:56 - MiscStage                         0         0              0         0                 0
19:55:37,085 StatusLogger.java:56 - CompactionExecutor                0         0          61989         0                 0
19:55:37,086 StatusLogger.java:56 - MemtableReclaimMemory             0         0            331         0                 0
19:55:37,087 StatusLogger.java:56 - PendingRangeCalculator            0         0              1         0                 0
19:55:37,088 StatusLogger.java:56 - GossipStage                       0         0              0         0                 0
19:55:37,089 StatusLogger.java:56 - MigrationStage                    0         0             17         0                 0
19:55:37,092 StatusLogger.java:56 - MemtablePostFlush                 0         0           2387         0                 0
19:55:37,095 StatusLogger.java:56 - ValidationExecutor                0         0              0         0                 0
19:55:37,097 StatusLogger.java:56 - Sampler                           0         0              0         0                 0
19:55:37,099 StatusLogger.java:56 - MemtableFlushWriter               0         0            331         0                 0
19:55:37,099 StatusLogger.java:56 - InternalResponseStage             0         0              0         0                 0
19:55:37,100 StatusLogger.java:56 - AntiEntropyStage                  0         0              0         0                 0
19:55:37,102 StatusLogger.java:56 - CacheCleanupExecutor              0         0              0         0                 0
19:55:37,102 StatusLogger.java:56 - Native-Transport-Requests         1         0        8356278         0            306061
19:55:37,116 StatusLogger.java:66 - CompactionManager                 0         0
19:55:37,122 StatusLogger.java:78 - MessagingService                n/a       0/0
19:55:37,122 StatusLogger.java:88 - Cache Type                     Size                 Capacity               KeysToSave
19:55:37,126 StatusLogger.java:90 - KeyCache                   50823767                104857600                      all
19:55:37,126 StatusLogger.java:96 - RowCache                          0                        0                      all
19:55:37,126 StatusLogger.java:103 - Table                       Memtable ops,data
19:55:37,144 StatusLogger.java:106 - system_distributed.parent_repair_history                 0,0
19:55:37,144 StatusLogger.java:106 - system_distributed.repair_history                 0,0
19:55:37,144 StatusLogger.java:106 - import_test.transactional_data    1199451,37053335
19:55:37,144 StatusLogger.java:106 - system.compaction_history               9,246
19:55:37,144 StatusLogger.java:106 - system.hints                              0,0
19:55:37,144 StatusLogger.java:106 - system.schema_aggregates                  0,0
19:55:37,144 StatusLogger.java:106 - system.IndexInfo                          0,0
19:55:37,145 StatusLogger.java:106 - system.schema_columnfamilies                 0,0
19:55:37,145 StatusLogger.java:106 - system.schema_triggers                    0,0
19:55:37,145 StatusLogger.java:106 - system.schema_functions                   0,0
19:55:37,145 StatusLogger.java:106 - system.size_estimates                520,3162
19:55:37,146 StatusLogger.java:106 - system.paxos                              0,0
19:55:37,146 StatusLogger.java:106 - system.peer_events                        0,0
19:55:37,146 StatusLogger.java:106 - system.range_xfers                        0,0
19:55:37,146 StatusLogger.java:106 - system.compactions_in_progress                 0,0
19:55:37,146 StatusLogger.java:106 - system.peers                              0,0
19:55:37,146 StatusLogger.java:106 - system.schema_keyspaces                   0,0
19:55:37,146 StatusLogger.java:106 - system.schema_usertypes                   0,0
19:55:37,146 StatusLogger.java:106 - system.local                              0,0
19:55:37,146 StatusLogger.java:106 - system.sstable_activity              418,1545
19:55:37,146 StatusLogger.java:106 - system.schema_columns                     0,0
19:55:37,146 StatusLogger.java:106 - system.batchlog                           0,0
19:55:37,147 StatusLogger.java:106 - system.available_ranges                   0,0
19:55:37,147 StatusLogger.java:106 - system_auth.roles                         0,0
19:55:37,147 StatusLogger.java:106 - system_auth.role_members                  0,0
19:55:37,147 StatusLogger.java:106 - system_auth.resource_role_permissons_index                 0,0
19:55:37,147 StatusLogger.java:106 - system_auth.role_permissions                 0,0
19:55:37,147 StatusLogger.java:106 - system_traces.sessions                    0,0
19:55:37,148 StatusLogger.java:106 - system_traces.events                      0,0
20:14:32,062 Memtable.java:352 - Writing Memtable-sstable_activity@1527249591(1.509KiB serialized bytes, 616 ops, 0%/0% of on/off-heap limit)
20:14:32,062 Memtable.java:352 - Writing Memtable-size_estimates@907520469(3.088KiB serialized bytes, 780 ops, 0%/0% of on/off-heap limit)
20:14:32,128 Memtable.java:352 - Writing Memtable-compaction_history@173198051(0.240KiB serialized bytes, 9 ops, 0%/0% of on/off-heap limit)
```

**Cassandra gc log**

```
2017-01-19T20:11:10.127+0100: 117198.441: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0020544 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0009831 seconds
{Heap before GC invocations=7026 (full 16):
 par new generation   total 737280K, used 664609K [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006f2000000, 0x00000006f2000000)
  eden space 655360K, 100% used [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006e8000000, 0x00000006e8000000)
  from space 81920K,  11% used [0x00000006ed000000, 0x00000006ed908710, 0x00000006f2000000)
  to   space 81920K,   0% used [0x00000006e8000000, 0x00000006e8000000, 0x00000006ed000000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 3375104K, used 1965475K [0x00000006f2000000, 0x00000007c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
 Metaspace       used 34481K, capacity 34783K, committed 35184K, reserved 1081344K
  class space    used 3678K, capacity 3772K, committed 3808K, reserved 1048576K
2017-01-19T20:11:12.390+0100: 117200.704: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2017-01-19T20:11:12.390+0100: 117200.704: [ParNew
Desired survivor size 41943040 bytes, new threshold 1 (max 1)
- age   1:    4114136 bytes,    4114136 total
: 664609K->7031K(737280K), 0.0122370 secs] 2630084K->1972513K(4112384K), 0.0123827 secs] [Times: user=0.03 sys=0.01, real=0.01 secs] 
Heap after GC invocations=7027 (full 16):
 par new generation   total 737280K, used 7031K [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006f2000000, 0x00000006f2000000)
  eden space 655360K,   0% used [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006e8000000)
  from space 81920K,   8% used [0x00000006e8000000, 0x00000006e86ddfe8, 0x00000006ed000000)
  to   space 81920K,   0% used [0x00000006ed000000, 0x00000006ed000000, 0x00000006f2000000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 3375104K, used 1965481K [0x00000006f2000000, 0x00000007c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
 Metaspace       used 34481K, capacity 34783K, committed 35184K, reserved 1081344K
  class space    used 3678K, capacity 3772K, committed 3808K, reserved 1048576K
}
2017-01-19T20:11:17.399+0100: 117205.714: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0274807 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0002973 seconds
{Heap before GC invocations=7028 (full 16):
 par new generation   total 737280K, used 670595K [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006f2000000, 0x00000006f2000000)
  eden space 655360K, 100% used [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006e8000000, 0x00000006e8000000)
  from space 81920K,  18% used [0x00000006ed000000, 0x00000006edee0c40, 0x00000006f2000000)
  to   space 81920K,   0% used [0x00000006e8000000, 0x00000006e8000000, 0x00000006ed000000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 3375104K, used 1965487K [0x00000006f2000000, 0x00000007c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
 Metaspace       used 34481K, capacity 34783K, committed 35184K, reserved 1081344K
  class space    used 3678K, capacity 3772K, committed 3808K, reserved 1048576K
2017-01-19T20:11:39.887+0100: 117228.201: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2017-01-19T20:11:39.887+0100: 117228.201: [ParNew
Desired survivor size 41943040 bytes, new threshold 1 (max 1)
- age   1:    4632832 bytes,    4632832 total
: 670595K->11530K(737280K), 0.0211463 secs] 2636082K->1977022K(4112384K), 0.0212837 secs] [Times: user=0.03 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs] 
Heap after GC invocations=7029 (full 16):
 par new generation   total 737280K, used 11530K [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006f2000000, 0x00000006f2000000)
  eden space 655360K,   0% used [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006e8000000)
  from space 81920K,  14% used [0x00000006e8000000, 0x00000006e8b428b0, 0x00000006ed000000)
  to   space 81920K,   0% used [0x00000006ed000000, 0x00000006ed000000, 0x00000006f2000000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 3375104K, used 1965491K [0x00000006f2000000, 0x00000007c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
 Metaspace       used 34481K, capacity 34783K, committed 35184K, reserved 1081344K
  class space    used 3678K, capacity 3772K, committed 3808K, reserved 1048576K
}
2017-01-19T20:12:10.131+0100: 117258.445: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0005586 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0002172 seconds
{Heap before GC invocations=7030 (full 16):
 par new generation   total 737280K, used 664725K [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006f2000000, 0x00000006f2000000)
  eden space 655360K, 100% used [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006e8000000, 0x00000006e8000000)
  from space 81920K,  11% used [0x00000006ed000000, 0x00000006ed925448, 0x00000006f2000000)
  to   space 81920K,   0% used [0x00000006e8000000, 0x00000006e8000000, 0x00000006ed000000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 3375104K, used 1965495K [0x00000006f2000000, 0x00000007c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
 Metaspace       used 34481K, capacity 34783K, committed 35184K, reserved 1081344K
  class space    used 3678K, capacity 3772K, committed 3808K, reserved 1048576K
2017-01-19T20:12:42.762+0100: 117291.077: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2017-01-19T20:12:42.762+0100: 117291.077: [ParNew
Desired survivor size 41943040 bytes, new threshold 1 (max 1)
- age   1:   15961696 bytes,   15961696 total
: 664725K->19181K(737280K), 0.0197058 secs] 2630220K->1984679K(4112384K), 0.0198265 secs] [Times: user=0.05 sys=0.01, real=0.02 secs] 
Heap after GC invocations=7031 (full 16):
 par new generation   total 737280K, used 19181K [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006f2000000, 0x00000006f2000000)
  eden space 655360K,   0% used [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006e8000000)
  from space 81920K,  23% used [0x00000006e8000000, 0x00000006e92bb500, 0x00000006ed000000)
  to   space 81920K,   0% used [0x00000006ed000000, 0x00000006ed000000, 0x00000006f2000000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 3375104K, used 1965498K [0x00000006f2000000, 0x00000007c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
 Metaspace       used 34481K, capacity 34783K, committed 35184K, reserved 1081344K
  class space    used 3678K, capacity 3772K, committed 3808K, reserved 1048576K
}
2017-01-19T20:13:13.099+0100: 117321.413: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0003673 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0000710 seconds
```

**Cassandra debug log**

```
20:14:03,669 SliceQueryPager.java:92 - Querying next page of slice query; new filter: SliceQueryFilter [reversed=false, slices=[[0010a7676a007a2949e490e58703550c222b0000047479706500, ]], count=5001, toGroup = 1]
20:14:03,670 FileCacheService.java:102 - Evicting cold readers for /home/cassandra/data/data/import_test/transactional_data-79c13380dd9111e6b9e0d333906ebbeb/lb-49-big-Data.db
20:14:03,709 AbstractQueryPager.java:95 - Fetched 2701 live rows
20:14:03,709 AbstractQueryPager.java:112 - Got result (2701) smaller than page size (5001), considering pager exhausted
20:14:03,712 AbstractQueryPager.java:133 - Remaining rows to page: 2147475947
20:14:09,201 SliceQueryPager.java:92 - Querying next page of slice query; new filter: SliceQueryFilter [reversed=false, slices=[[, ]], count=5000, toGroup = 1]
20:14:09,202 FileCacheService.java:102 - Evicting cold readers for /home/cassandra/data/data/import_test/transactional_data-79c13380dd9111e6b9e0d333906ebbeb/lb-49-big-Data.db
20:14:09,282 AbstractQueryPager.java:95 - Fetched 5000 live rows
20:14:09,282 AbstractQueryPager.java:133 - Remaining rows to page: 2147478647
20:14:10,153 ColumnFamilyStore.java:980 - forceFlush requested but everything is clean in batchlog
20:14:24,442 SliceQueryPager.java:92 - Querying next page of slice query; new filter: SliceQueryFilter [reversed=false, slices=[[0010a8ceba29bcec45b7b66323cbb506f09a0000047479706500, ]], count=5001, toGroup = 1]
20:14:24,443 FileCacheService.java:102 - Evicting cold readers for /home/cassandra/data/data/import_test/transactional_data-79c13380dd9111e6b9e0d333906ebbeb/lb-49-big-Data.db
20:14:24,489 AbstractQueryPager.java:95 - Fetched 2701 live rows
20:14:24,489 AbstractQueryPager.java:112 - Got result (2701) smaller than page size (5001), considering pager exhausted
20:14:24,492 AbstractQueryPager.java:133 - Remaining rows to page: 2147475947
20:14:32,039 ColumnFamilyStore.java:927 - Enqueuing flush of sstable_activity: 13998 (0%) on-heap, 0 (0%) off-heap
20:14:32,050 ColumnFamilyStore.java:927 - Enqueuing flush of size_estimates: 42686 (0%) on-heap, 0 (0%) off-heap
20:14:32,064 ColumnFamilyStore.java:927 - Enqueuing flush of compaction_history: 1197 (0%) on-heap, 0 (0%) off-heap
20:14:32,062 Memtable.java:352 - Writing Memtable-size_estimates@907520469(3.088KiB serialized bytes, 780 ops, 0%/0% of on/off-heap limit)
20:14:32,086 Memtable.java:386 - Completed flushing /home/cassandra/data/data/system/size_estimates-618f817b005f3678b8a453f3930b8e86/tmp-lb-198-big-Data.db (0.000KiB) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segmentId=1484733263564, position=31840472)
20:14:32,128 Memtable.java:352 - Writing Memtable-compaction_history@173198051(0.240KiB serialized bytes, 9 ops, 0%/0% of on/off-heap limit)
20:14:32,130 Memtable.java:386 - Completed flushing /home/cassandra/data/data/system/compaction_history-b4dbb7b4dc493fb5b3bfce6e434832ca/tmp-lb-151-big-Data.db (0.000KiB) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segmentId=1484733263564, position=31840472)
20:14:32,150 CompactionTask.java:142 - Compacting (81ce1850-de7b-11e6-b9e0-d333906ebbeb) [/home/cassandra/data/data/system/sstable_activity-5a1ff267ace03f128563cfae6103c65e/lb-198-big-Data.db:level=0, /home/cassandra/data/data/system/sstable_activity-5a1ff267ace03f128563cfae6103c65e/lb-199-big-Data.db:level=0, /home/cassandra/data/data/system/sstable_activity-5a1ff267ace03f128563cfae6103c65e/lb-200-big-Data.db:level=0, /home/cassandra/data/data/system/sstable_activity-5a1ff267ace03f128563cfae6103c65e/lb-197-big-Data.db:level=0, ]
20:14:32,190 FileCacheService.java:177 - Invalidating cache for /home/cassandra/data/data/system/sstable_activity-5a1ff267ace03f128563cfae6103c65e/tmplink-lb-201-big-Data.db
20:14:32,198 FileCacheService.java:177 - Invalidating cache for /home/cassandra/data/data/system/sstable_activity-5a1ff267ace03f128563cfae6103c65e/lb-200-big-Data.db
20:14:32,198 CompactionTask.java:224 - Compacted (81ce1850-de7b-11e6-b9e0-d333906ebbeb) 4 sstables to [/home/cassandra/data/data/system/sstable_activity-5a1ff267ace03f128563cfae6103c65e/lb-201-big,] to level=0.  4,012 bytes to 939 (~23% of original) in 40ms = 0.022388MB/s.  0 total partitions merged to 17.  Partition merge counts were {1:12, 4:17, }
20:14:32,198 FileCacheService.java:102 - Evicting cold readers for /home/cassandra/data/data/import_test/transactional_data-79c13380dd9111e6b9e0d333906ebbeb/lb-85-big-Data.db
20:14:32,201 FileCacheService.java:177 - Invalidating cache for /home/cassandra/data/data/system/sstable_activity-5a1ff267ace03f128563cfae6103c65e/lb-197-big-Data.db
20:14:32,800 SliceQueryPager.java:92 - Querying next page of slice query; new filter: SliceQueryFilter [reversed=false, slices=[[, ]], count=5000, toGroup = 1]
20:14:32,800 FileCacheService.java:102 - Evicting cold readers for /home/cassandra/data/data/import_test/transactional_data-79c13380dd9111e6b9e0d333906ebbeb/lb-49-big-Data.db
20:14:54,860 AbstractQueryPager.java:112 - Got result (2701) smaller than page size (5001), considering pager exhausted
20:14:54,862 AbstractQueryPager.java:133 - Remaining rows to page: 2147475947
20:15:05,797 SliceQueryPager.java:92 - Querying next page of slice query; new filter: SliceQueryFilter [reversed=false, slices=[[, ]], count=5000, toGroup = 1]
20:15:05,797 FileCacheService.java:102 - Evicting cold readers for /home/cassandra/data/data/import_test/transactional_data-79c13380dd9111e6b9e0d333906ebbeb/lb-49-big-Data.db
20:15:05,876 AbstractQueryPager.java:95 - Fetched 5000 live rows
20:15:05,876 AbstractQueryPager.java:133 - Remaining rows to page: 2147478647
20:15:10,153 ColumnFamilyStore.java:980 - forceFlush requested but everything is clean in batchlog
20:15:51,040 SliceQueryPager.java:92 - Querying next page of slice query; new filter: SliceQueryFilter [reversed=false, slices=[[0010a5a53060d5d043f2832958356689c4ee0000047479706500, ]], count=5001, toGroup = 1]
20:15:51,040 FileCacheService.java:102 - Evicting cold readers for /home/cassandra/data/data/import_test/transactional_data-79c13380dd9111e6b9e0d333906ebbeb/lb-49-big-Data.db
20:15:51,083 AbstractQueryPager.java:95 - Fetched 2701 live rows
20:15:51,083 AbstractQueryPager.java:112 - Got result (2701) smaller than page size (5001), considering pager exhausted
20:15:51,086 AbstractQueryPager.java:133 - Remaining rows to page: 2147475947
20:18:10,161 ColumnFamilyStore.java:980 - forceFlush requested but everything is clean in batchlog
20:18:42,277 FileCacheService.java:102 - Evicting cold readers for /home/cassandra/data/data/system/local-7ad54392bcdd35a684174e047860b377/lb-134-big-Data.db
```

Comment: looks like your application went out of memory, not cassandra.

Comment: Out of memory because you retain references to all records in `resultLists`. Either discard records after reading (processing) or use smaller batches.

Comment: As the folks above say its the application that's the problem here it seems? The drivers docs here might help you: http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/2.1/manual/paging/